# Why is Agda refusing Set₁ → Set₁?

Tags: agda

Here's the code:

```
Continuation : Set → Set₁ → Set₁
Continuation R X = (X → R) → R

Selection : Set → Set₁ → Set₁
Selection R X = (X → R) → X

dagger : {R : Set} → Selection R → Continuation R
dagger S X k = k (S k)
```

I need continuation and selection to use a higher universe for other reasons. But then the definition of dagger raises an error:

> (Set₁ → Set₁) should be a sort, but it isn't when checking that the inferred type of an application
> Set₁ → Set₁
> matches the expected type _16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Agda `_→_` is the function space not of any category but that of types and
functions. My guess is that you want the following:

```
dagger : {R : Set} → ∀ X → Selection R X → Continuation R X
dagger X S k = k (S k)
```

i.e. the function space of indexed types and index-preserving functions.

Alternatively you could make this clear by using the stdlib's
`Relation.Unary` notion of morphism and write:

```
open import Relation.Unary

dagger : {R : Set} → Selection R ⊆ Continuation R
dagger S k = k (S k)
```

Comment: Thanks! So I understand the correction but I don't understand what you mean with the first sentence.

Comment: You can ignore the first sentence. I assumed you were coming from category theory because you tried to write code that way. If it's not the case then that explanation won't help you. As long as you get the fix, that's what counts.

Comment: Yeah your guess is right. So maybe I see what I tried to do was not right for what I wanted to do. I still don't understand the error, probably because I don't know what type `_16` is supposed to be. Wouldn't it be acceptable to write a function from Set1 to Set1?

Comment: When Agda is sortchecking a type, it doesn't know what sort to expect. I expect that `_16` is the internal metavariable for the unknown sort. It's a little unpolished when such things leak out into user-facing diagnostics, but I've got three more fingers, pointing back at me.